# Web service WSDL - Type Expansion and backward compatibility

Tags: web-services, wsdl

I have a requirement to add additonal enumeration items to a web service response and I want to know any best practices around this. I assume this is considered a non-backward compatible change?

Should I employ a web service versioning aproach here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please give details of what you need to do. What do you mean "additional enumeration items"?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description it sounds like you could just make the additional elements optional (minOccurs=0) to keep the WSDL backward compatible without major changes usually required for versioning for backward compatibility. Here is a nice article on the subject: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/ws-soa-backcomp/